# Unable to deploy Flask App in AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying a flask app in the Elastic Beanstalk environment in AWS. It works completely fine in my local, but when I upload the same to Beanstalk, I get the following error in the Log Files.

```
[ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [InstallDependency]. Stop running the command. Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /bin/sh -c /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tu8sxhxj/mysqlclient_f51fe93483714a68ae43574db1c80ed5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tu8sxhxj/mysqlclient_f51fe93483714a68ae43574db1c80ed5/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-abr_xfaw
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tu8sxhxj/mysqlclient_f51fe93483714a68ae43574db1c80ed5/
    Complete output (15 lines):
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
    /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tu8sxhxj/mysqlclient_f51fe93483714a68ae43574db1c80ed5/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tu8sxhxj/mysqlclient_f51fe93483714a68ae43574db1c80ed5/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-tu8sxhxj/mysqlclient_f51fe93483714a68ae43574db1c80ed5/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
        raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    mysql_config --version
    mariadb_config --version
    mysql_config --libs
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/df/59cd2fa5e48d0804d213bdcb1acb4d08c403b61c7ff7ed4dd4a6a2deb3f7/mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=f6ebea7c008f155baeefe16c56cd3ee6239f7a5a9ae42396c2f1860f08a7c432 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient==2.0.3
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient==2.0.3
 

2021/04/04 16:02:21.681275 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/04/04 16:02:21.681366 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1617552141,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1617552141,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

My requirements.txt file is as below:

```
aniso8601==8.0.0
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-JWT==0.3.2
Flask-MySQLdb==0.2.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.3
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mysqlclient==2.0.3
PyJWT==1.4.2
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.18
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Even when I tried doing pip install -r requirements.txt for the first time in my local, I faced the same issue.

However, I resolved it using the following steps

```
1. $ brew install mysql
2. $ pip install mysqlclient
```

I assume something similar needs to be done in the server. Can someone help me figure out how can this be run in the server?

Comment: Perhaps easiest to replace mysqlclient with a pure Python mysql client, perhaps [PyMySQL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.pymysql) would work.

Comment: If this does not work on your local, maybe first try fixing it?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - thanks for the suggestion!! Works like a charm now.. A much cleaner approach indeed.

Comment: @AnamikAdhikary to continue, there is a way to install some Amazon Linux packages to Elastic Beanstalk using the yaml configs, that way you could install the mysql client in there. But all in all that is a mess, and I consider Elastic Beanstalk usable only with docker containers, but at that point there is not much advantage you get from Elastic Beanstalk as opposed to using Fargate...

Comment: Noted!! Thanks @AnttiHaapala